# number of checkbox being ticked doesn't equal to what's shown on the page

Tags: java, mysql

I want to check two checkbox on this web page to delete those rows. However, when I press the delete button, it displays "0 record(s) deleted". Besides, both rows of data that I checked was not deleted. What should i do to solve this problem?

Display(ticked 2 box):

[image]

Webpage shown after I clicked the delete button:

[image]

**Code for my delete button**

```
    <%
    String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("userAction");
    int count=0;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Step 2: Define Connection URL
        String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medicloud?user=root&password=root";
        // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

        if (ids != null)
        {
        for(int i=0; i<ids.length; i++){

        String sqlStr = "DELETE from exercise1 && exercise2 WHERE id=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ids[i]));
        //pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ids[i]));
        int rec=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rec==1)
            count++;
        }
        }


            //System.out.println(functions);
%>
    <form action="exercise.jsp" method="post">
        <label><%=count%> record(s) deleted!!</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Return" name="ReturnBtn" />
    </form>
<%

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

Comment: please use catch block to see the error `try {
    //..your code    
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}`

Comment: beside It seems that your query is not correct syntax `DELETE from exercise1 && exercise2 WHERE id=?` did you try it in your DBMS

Comment: Are your checkboxes inside the same form as your delete button?  And what is the value of their `name` attribute?

Comment: There is no error after i use that function @YCF_L

Comment: ** This is my delete button form** `code`
<form action="delete.jsp" id="multipleDele" method="post">
  <strong>Selected Exercise(s) to: </strong><input type="submit"
  value="Delete" id="mulDelBtn" name="deleteMultipleBtn" />
]</form>

Comment: **This is my checkbox form** `code` <td style="width: 5%"><input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox"
  value="<%=id%>" form="multipleDele" name="userAction" /></td>

Comment: OK, so the checkboxes are probably fine.  Did you take YCF_L's advice and fix up the SQL syntax?  I think you'll need two separate SQL statements - one to delete from exercise1 and one to delete from exercise2.

Comment: Yes, i have created one to delete from exercise1 and one to delete from exercise2.